# To make a new column from calculated column select in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data covid death record on a specific date from 2020 until 2022 in a specific. I want to calculate the death percentage for 2 years for every countries using group by of the country.

I try to make the query as such but the query won't work because using subquery as an expression is not allowed. How do I make this query work? Thank you.

```
SELECT 
   location, 
   sum(total_deaths) as total_deaths, 
   sum(total_cases) as total_cases, 
   (select SUM(total_deaths) 
    FROM CovidDeaths$ 
    GROUP BY location
   )/
   (select sum(total_cases) 
    FROM CovidDeaths$ 
    GROUP BY location
   ) *100 as DeathPercentage 
FROM CovidDeaths$ 
WHERE NOT (total_deaths is null 
           OR total_cases is null 
           OR continent is null
          ) 
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY 1
```

*location in the query refers to country

I try to make nested query but the value of death percentage become 0.

```
SELECT location, total_deaths1, total_cases1, total_deaths1/total_cases1*100 as Death_Percentage

FROM(

SELECT location, sum(total_deaths) as total_deaths1, sum(total_cases) as total_cases1

FROM CovidDeaths$ 

WHERE NOT (total_deaths is null OR total_cases is null OR continent is null) 

GROUP BY location

) as death

ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: `Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL.` => Please tag your question with the database you are using, ideally including the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many databases use integer arithmetic when integers are used in division.  As there are no integers between `0` and `1`, this means that all your values are being rounded down to `0` before mutliplying by `100`.

- `2 / 6 * 100` => `0 * 100` => `0`

You could simply change the order of the operations

- `100 * 2 / 6` => `200 / 6` => `66`

Or, implicitly convert the values to a non-integer type

- `100.0 * 2 / 6` => `200.0 / 6` => `33.3333333`

You can also use `CAST()`, `CONVERT()`, or other functions to ***explicitly*** convert the data-type *(perhaps to `DECIMAL(18,6)` or `FLOAT`, depending on your needs)*.

- Exact syntax depends on which database you are using
- But you haven't specified which database that is

Comment: I changed the order of the operations it calculated the death percentage correctly. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to calculate the average in a subquery, you can just calculate it in your main query

```
(SUM(total_deaths)/sum(total_cases))*100
```

UPDATE

This calculated column is part of your main query which you are grouping by location:

```
SELECT 
location, 
sum(total_deaths) as total_deaths, 
sum(total_cases) as total_cases, 
(SUM(total_deaths)/sum(total_cases))*100
FROM CovidDeaths$ 
WHERE NOT (total_deaths is null 
       OR total_cases is null 
       OR continent is null
      ) 
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: But I want the total deaths and the total cases for each of the countries. Not all total deaths of the row.

Comment: @SofiyahRahmat - Switching between the terms "location" and "country" isn't helpful.  Are they the same thing?  *(If so, stick to the term used in the code.)*  Then, what is the difference between "total for a row" and "total for a location"?  *(Ideally, demosntrate the difference with examples in your question.)*